# Some links refers to localhost but hosts file is fine

Tags: windows

I am not sure what tags to add on this question. I will describe my situation as well as I can.

I open the virtual hosts at the chrome, run the phpstorm, read php code. After I searching the question of the code, then I refresh the page, and I am in trouble.

It is so sudden which is never happened before. I tried to figure out what is going on, but I got nothing.

All I know is some links refers to localhost automaticly and I have no idea about it.

The problem website is https://www.iviewui.com/docs/guide/install as far as I know.

I press f12, switch to Network panel and get these. 
[image]

It seems https://file.iviewui.com/dist/main.9011c9acade2093b2da7.css not works well, so I visit https://file.iviewui.com directly then it shows me `Access forbidden!` . Ok, I visit http://file.iviewui.com, and it really confuses me that it shows the same result of localhost.
[image]

However I am not put the website into `hosts` file.
[image]

I have doubted that it might be caused by the proxy plugin. I open another brower firefox, still get the same result.
[image]

Also doubted that it might be caused by the virus, but it doesn't make sense. Actually I did use the safemgr software and still got nothing.

Tried stoping apache of xampp and get ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED which means it really refers to localhost.

Before I ask this question, bootstrap website has the same problem.I was editing this question meanwhile I visited bootstrap website again and problem disappeared. I still don't know why and iView website still has the problem.

Tried restarting the computer and problem is still there.

Comment: Are you in China? What IP address do you get if you execute an `nslookup file.iviewui.com`? What proxy plugin are you talking about, can you uninstall it entirely?

Comment: Yes, I run the command you gave me and it shows me **DNS request timed out, timeout was 2 seconds. Server Unknown. Adress: 192.168.1.1**.  I am not sure what is the translation of __非权威应答__, so I google it and it gives me `Non-authoritative answer`. The content is  **name: file.iviewui.com, Address: 127.0.0.1**.

Comment: By the way, I can visit the website 2 hours ago. It just happened so suddenly. And proxy plugin might not be the initiator, because firefox does not install the plugin and problem is still there.

Comment: Eliminate all possible causes. Perhaps the Chrome proxy plugin (which one?) installs a system-wide proxy. But then again, a proxy has nothing to do with DNS. It looks like your router, 192.168.1.1 tells your computer that the IP address for that hostname is 127.0.0.1. Try resetting it, or try managing it via its web interface. Anyhow, it looks like you've messed up your computer's network configuration, and that's not on-topic for Stack Overflow. Try Super User, and explain **everything** you've done to your machine.

Comment: Proxy plugin is SwitchyOmega, but the iView page went wrong before I run the proxy software. I follow your way of thinking, google for some suggestions. I tried `ipconfig /flushdns` and nothing changed. Then I quit the safemgr software and iView website can be visited. And I restart the safemgr software again but the website sitll can be visited. That is so weird for me, so I restart the computer and try to visit again and it seems problem is solved. I think ipconfig /flushdns command works. @CodeCaster Thanks for your help. :)